# FindBy Id method in EntityFramework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, repository-pattern

it is possible to implement FindBy method in Entity framework while we have this GenericRepository class :

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {

        private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;
public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            //IQueryable<T> query=_entitySet.
        }
}
```

how can I Implement FindBy in this case !??

Comment: imply by adding one line of code!  return _entitySet.Where(predicate);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Repository has the following method to return a single entity by a given expression.

```
public T FindSingle(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) {
  return _entitySet.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Now the caller can use any expression to get a single entity, like

```
var entity = _repository.FindSingle(entity=> entity.Id == 23);
```

or

```
var entity = _repository.FindSingle(entity=> entity.Name == "Hello World");
```

If your interface IAggregateRoot defines a property Id you can also add an an explicit method to your generic interface to get a single entity by its Id.

```
public interface IAggregateRoot {
  int Id {get;}
}

public class GenericRepository {
  public T FindSingleById(int id) {
    return _entitySet.FirstOrDefault(entity=>entity.Id == id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {

        private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;
        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return _entitySet.Where(predicate).
        }
}
```

Comment: yeah , but there is another problem that if  want to return T instead of IQueryable<T> , what I have to do ??

Comment: @EricNielsen you want to return a single instance? then use `FirstOrDefault()` or `SingleOrDefault()` after `Where`

Comment: it is a FindById method and I wanna to return a record by Id , and it is obvious that return a T (ViewModel) not a IQueryable<ViewModel> !