# FindBy method Entity framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have this *account Model*:

```
 public class Account :IAggregateRoot
    { 
        public Account()
        {
        }
        public Account(Guid accountId)
        {
            Id = accountId;
        }

        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
      }
}
```

and this *repository class* :

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
    {

        private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;

        public T FindBy(T entity)
        {
            return _entitySet.Find(entity);
        }
     }
```

and now when I want to get an entity by Id , for example :

```
 public AccountViewModel GetAccountBy(Guid accountId)
        {
            var account = new Account(accountId);
            _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.FindBy(account);
            var accountView = account.ConvertToAccountView();
            return  accountView;
        }
```

I got this *Error* :

```
The specified parameter type is not valid. Only scalar types, such as System.Int32, System.Decimal, System.DateTime, and System.Guid, are supported.
```

my action to call *GetAccountBy* is like this:

```
 public ActionResult Edit(Guid accountId)
        {
            var account = _accountService.GetAccountBy(accountId);
            return View(account);
        }
```

what is problem with this ? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [FindBy Id method in EntityFramework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865013/findby-id-method-in-entityframework)

Comment: edit your existing question before starting a new one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not calling the `DBSet.Find()` method correctly.

[As the documentation states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset.find%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) you need to pass

> The values of the primary key for the entity to be found

you don't pass in an *instance* of the entity, you pass in the *key values* that identify an entity. From your example you don't need to create a new instance of account:

```
var account = new Account(accountId);
_unitOfWork.AccountRepository.FindBy(account);
```

you just need to pass the `accountId` to `FindBy()`

```
_unitOfWork.AccountRepository.FindBy(accountId);
```

Here's your code amended:

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAggregateRoot
{

    private readonly DbSet<T> _entitySet;

    public T FindBy(params Object[] keyValues)
    {
        return _entitySet.Find(keyValues)
    }
}

public AccountViewModel GetAccountBy(Guid accountId)
{
    _unitOfWork.AccountRepository.FindBy(accountId);
    var accountView = account.ConvertToAccountView();
    return  accountView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the DbSet.Find(params object[] keyValues) Method only with System.Int32  and System.Guid as the error message indicates. (well and System.Decimal, System.DateTime probably for composite keys)

The method will not look for a Id or PK in your Model and use it automatically (when you pass Account, the method will not use Account.Id) - as its using "the primary key value" http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418(v=vs.103).aspx

Consider passing a predicate as suggested in [FindBy Id method in EntityFramework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14865013/findby-id-method-in-entityframework)

If you Models always have an Id of Type Guid, then maybe you can pass the Id directly:

```
public T FindBy(T entity)
        {
            return _entitySet.Find(entity.Id);
        }
```

Hope this helps.